# HashMap.this.clear() what does this mean, how does this work

Tags: java, collections

In `HashMap` class there is an inner class `KeySet` whose instance is returned by the `HashMap`'s instance method `keySet()`. This inner class contains the following method.

```
public void clear() {
    HashMap.this.clear();
}
```

I understand the general semantics of "`this`"

1. It is a reference to the "current" object.
2. Can be used within constructors or any instance methods where it acts as a reference to the object being constructed or the object whose methods are being invoked.

The above style of using "`this`" seems interesting,

1. It is being used as if its a static variable of a class.
2. It should still be referring to an object whose method is being invoked. In this logically it should be an HashMap instance.

Given the above two it should be possible to have a static reference to any dynamically created instance object but that's not possible since there could be infinite number of instances at runtime and there aren’t any language constructs to specify this relation between a class and its instances.

I am definitely missing something, can someone help me understand this better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When a non-static inner class is created, it gets a reference to its enclosing class instance. In order to reference that instance, a special syntax is used: the keyword `this` is prefixed with the name of the enclosing class. When used without a class name prefix, `this` keyword refers to the instance of the inner class itself.

Essentially, the call is made to the `clear` method of the `HashMap` class. Note that since the method of the inner class is called `clear` as well, the call without `HashMap.this` would have been directed to the `clear()` inside the inner class, causing infinite recursion.

As correctly stated by Roger Lindsjö in a comment below  Technically the idiom is known as *qualified this* construct. [(JLS 15.8.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, can you give some reference.

Comment: @kunkunur See the section on Shadowing here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: To be more clear it is called a "Qualified this" (JLS 15.8.4).

Comment: @kunkunur For full description of the qualified this is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) on page 431.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap.this.clear();` calls the current instance of `HashMap`, you mentioned that its calling from a InnerClass, so that's how its referencing the Outter class.